# Is "--no-web" option removed from Locust 2.6.1

Tags: python, performance, testing, locust

I'm trying to use locust 2.6.1 in no web mode but it's throwing following error

```
$>locust -f load_testing_class_based.py --no-web -c 1000 -r 100 --run-time 2m
locust: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-web -c
```

Also, how to add time limit for execution??
I ran this with web ui

```
$>locust -f load_testing_class_based.py -t 120s
```

but execution continued even after 2 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`—no-web` was renamed `—headless` a while back.

`-t` only applies to headless (and autostart) runs.

Comment: yeah.. I found it in help, very immediately after posting a question